# range of $k$ in quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

the exhaustive set of values of $k$ for which  $|kx-2|=2x^2+kx+4$ has at least one positive root

solution i try $|kx-2|$ is either $(kx-2)$ or $-(kx-2)$

$kx-2=2x^2+kx+4\Rightarrow 2x^2=-6$ no real solution

$-kx+2=2x^2+kx+4\Rightarrow x^2+kx+4=0$

$\displaystyle x=\frac{-k\pm \sqrt{k^2-16}}{4}$

$|k|\geq 4$ i did not understand how i use condition at least one positive root

Comment: You have found k for a real root. You still need to make it a positive root.

Comment: @user14096 Does $x^2+kx+4=0$ really follow after $−kx+2=2x^2+kx+4$? After you fix that issue, you can put the bounds into the equation you have, and see if the root is positive or negative. The remaining area should be your inequality.

Comment: Hint: Your second equation is incorrect, and $$|k| = \sqrt{k^2} = \sqrt{(-k)^2} = |-k|$$

Answer (score 3):

If $-kx + 2 = 2x^2 + kx + 4$ then $2 = 2x^2 + 2kx + 4$ thus $0 = 2x^2 + 2kx - 2$. $$\therefore x^2 + kx - 1 = 0\tag1$$ and not $$x^2 + kx + 4 = 0.\tag2$$ Equation $(1)$ is correct, but Eq. $(2)$ is false. Therefore, you should have that $$x = \frac{-k\pm\sqrt{k^2 - 4}}{2}$$ which brings us to the fact that $|k|\geq 2$. Since we need a positive root $x$, then for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have $k^2 - 4 = n^2$. Since $4 = 2^2$ then we have that $k = 2$. $$\therefore x = \frac{-2\pm 0}{2} = -1.$$ This means that $k\neq 2$ because in this case, $x<0$. But, remember that $2^2 = (-2)^2$ so that means we can let $k = -2$. $$\therefore x = \frac{2\pm 0}{2} = 1.$$ It follows, then, that $(k, x) = (-2, 1)$ and $x$ has at least one positve solution.